# Xcode gives three syntax errors dealing with Stray '\342' in program

Tags: c, objective-c, syntax, compiler-errors

I am working on a simple project in Objective-C in Xcode, and I'm getting some stray/ errors about the following line of code:

```
if(celsius < −273.15) {
    NSLog(@"It is impossible to convert temperatures less than −273.15 degrees Celsius, because this is absolute zero, the coldest possible temperature.");
}
```

It's actually only about the first line, but I wanted to give some context.

Any suggestions?

I've looked it up here on SO, but everyone else's error hasn't had such simple code like mine, although it appears they have a common problem of having the wrong encoding for certain punctuation, perhaps?

It's got to be just some syntax this in my *if* statement...

It looks as though it also displays two other stray errors:

Stray '\210' 
Stray '\222'

Comment: The real reason is probably copying code from a web page, PDF document, or through chat, like Skype Chat (or other formatted text).

Comment: The canonical is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Comment: The 3 stray errors is one unit and are octal numbers: 342 210 222 (octal) → 0xE2 0x88 0x92 (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+2212 ([MINUS SIGN](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8704&number=128)).

Comment: A question with this specific error is *[Error with stray ‘\342’ stray ‘\210’ stray ‘\222’ in C program in Linux system call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38343182)*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

− != -

Your minus, isn't a minus.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks, sorry for wasting your time, what did the compiler recognize mine as?

Comment: Looks like yours is a 'minus sign' whereas the compiler expects a 'hyphen-minus'.

Comment: Cool, thanks, when I use this code however: if(celsius < -!=-273.15), I get the following error, except only 1 this time, no stray:  error: expected expression before '!=' token

Comment: if(celsius < -!=-273.15) that expression makes no sense. You mean if(celsius < -273.15)?

Comment: Copy this directly..

if (celsius < -273.15)

And fix the encoding on your file

Comment: Wait, sorry, I see what you mean the first time, my bad, I just copied and pasted your last comment and it worked perfectly..

Comment: Glad its fixed, I'm not sure how you're accidentally using those characters though. Is your language set to something other than english?

Comment: Hmm, good point, no, I'm using Xcode 3.2.3 on Snow Leopard with English language..

Comment: Nope, actually, all I did was press the standard dash / minus key on my macbook's keyboard, the one right next to 0.

Comment: I had this issue as well. Copy and pasting the function protocols from the documentation fixed the issue.

Comment: To be more precise, it is Unicode code point U+2212 ([MINUS SIGN](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8704&number=128)). In most text editors it can be searched/replaced by a regular expression search for `\x{2212}`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your " characters are straight up and down (and not of the left/right slanted variety).