# Error with stray ‘\342’ stray ‘\210’ stray ‘\222’ in C program in Linux system call

Tags: c++, c, linux, systems-programming

I am trying to do an example on a poll system call from Robert Love's book *Linux system programming, 2nd edition* (page 60-61). I copy pasted the example code in [Code::Blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks) on [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) and tried compiling it, but I get errors related to stray '/342' '/210' and '/222' in my code.

Following is the code: It throws error on line 18 where if(ret == -1) is checked

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <poll.h>

#define TIMEOUT 5

/* Poll timeout, in seconds */
int main (void)
{
  struct pollfd fds[2];
  int ret;

  /* Watch standard input for input */
  fds[0].fd = STDIN_FILENO;
  fds[0].events = POLLIN;

  /* Watch standard output for ability to write (almost always true) */
  fds[1].fd = STDOUT_FILENO;
  fds[1].events = POLLOUT;

  /* All set, block! */
  ret = poll(fds, 2 , TIMEOUT*1000);

  if (ret == −1) {
    perror("poll");
    return 1;
  }

  if (!ret) {
    printf ("%d seconds elapsed.\n", TIMEOUT);
    return 0;
  }

  if (fds[0].revents & POLLIN)
    printf ("stdin is readable\n");

  if (fds[1].revents & POLLOUT)
    printf ("stdout is writable\n");

  return 0;
 }
```

The errors are:

```
/home/eelab/sysprog/pollex/main.c|18| error: stray ‘\342’ in program|
/home/eelab/sysprog/pollex/main.c|18| error: stray ‘\210’ in program|
/home/eelab/sysprog/pollex/main.c|18| error: stray ‘\222’ in program|
```

Now, I've gone through similar questions on Stack Overflow and they mention the possible problem being with conversion of ASCII characters like quotes " ". However, I have rewritten all quotes in the IDE again. But it still throws the same error on the line where if(ret == -1 ) is checked.

Comment: its not really a duplicate

Comment: The real duplicate is the canonical *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*.

Comment: A much more direct analysis is 342 210 222 (octal) → 0xE2 0x88 0x92 (hexadecimal) → UTF-8 sequence for Unicode code point U+2212 ([MINUS SIGN](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8704&number=128)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the unprintable `−` on

```
if (ret == −1) {
```

Replace it with `-`

Comment: Thanks bro.It works :)

Comment: To be more precise, it is Unicode code point U+2212 ([MINUS SIGN](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8704&number=128)). In most text editors it can be searched/replaced by a regular expression search for `\x{2212}`.